# Not able to insert text in textbox using Selenium (using firefox)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to insert text into a text box. When I inspect the textbox I found out that their are no identifiers for the text box so I used the xpath.

[On inspecting the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFNmX.png)

```
textbox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/main/article/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/textarea")
textbox.click()
textbox.send_keys("convert")
```

But it throws an error

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'".

I tried to find out where the text gets written and it is written in Code-line class.
[Code gets written here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0TMO.png)

I don't understand what's actually going on here because I have not seen any textbox which don't have any identifier.

**How can I identify the textbox and insert text into it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` instead of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`

**`driver.find_element_by_xpath`** returns single webelement so you can perform the action like `click` or `sendkeys`

**`driver.find_elements_by_xpath`** returns list of webelement So you need to iterate the list to extract the webelement one by one

Comment: When I do that It throws another exception.           selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <textarea> could not be scrolled into view